# Recursively enumerate files and dirs in C#

Tags: c#, macos, mono, c#-2.0

On MacOS using Mono, when I list files and dirs with `Directory.GetFiles()` I get `System.UnathorizedAcessException` and it stops enumerating. Anyone knows how to make it continue or maybe a different approach to enum files

EDIT:
I wrote my own method, seems to work.

```
        static void DirSearch(string sDir) {
        try {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*")) {
                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                }

                DirSearch(d);
            }
        } catch { }
        }
```

EDIT: 
I wonder will that code exit on the first exception?

Comment: Can you include which directories you're attempting to read from, their privileges, the privilege that your app is running with and if you're expecting these folders to be written to during the enumeration?

Comment: Admin account, mono myapp.exe, trying /private/var/folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a try/catch around the `Directory.GetFiles()`, you should just be able to go on with the next directory if it fails. You can even wrap this like this:

```
private string[] SafeGetFilesForDirectory(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: An unspecified `catch` is usually not a good idea. Just catch the exceptions you're worried about; in this case, `UnauthorizedAccessException`.